# What’s windup angels

Tags: word-usage

**Wind up** means to find yourself in an unexpected and usually unpleasant situation, especially as a result of what you do in Cambridge Dictionary.

But I saw it come to one word in a book(**windup angels** that fluttered around the bedroom like startled sparrows), and I am confused with it .I also found there are some different usage like **wind-up** or **windup** or **wind sth up** and **wind up**,but not really sure the exact meaning behind those words.

Comment: [Definition of windup](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/windup) (adj) : operated by a spring mechanism wound by hand

Comment: From _Coraline_ by Neil Gaiman (which you should have mentioned).

Comment: It's **wind-up** with a **hyphen** in my copy of this book. We usually hyphenate compound adjectives if they occur before the noun that they modify.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: There are two instances of hyphenated ***wind-up*** in Google books for this text, and two instances *without* the hyphen. But both the unhyphenated versions are in books with the title ***Коралина / Coraline***, so perhaps they're unauthorized Russian copies that weren't properly checked. I can't believe the *legitimate* publishers would have decided to remove that hyphen for the Russian market (the way they make dorky changes to JK Rowling's British-oriented text for the US market! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Rowling's text is dorky enough to begin with, if you ask me.

Comment: I didn't, because I already knew that lol. But actually I think modern writers like JK Rowling and Jeffrey Archer have excellent smooth-flowing prose styles. Dickens and Kerouac were good in their day, but *they've had their day!*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would say that the only writer with a worse, and more clunky, prose style than Rowling is Archer. Her style is full of over-exposition, over-description, and redundant adverbs.

Comment: Degrees at dawn! Mine's called *English and French Language and Literature with Linguistics*. Not that relevant to a career in software development, but it might have helped me get commissions writing crossword / wordsearch / codeword generating software. In which context, I recall that my main customers in the 80s specifically had me exclude the word ***Jew*** from all answers and clues, but I'll bet even if I'd raised the matter, they wouldn't have cared about ***Jap***. And of course, ***Nip*** could be used with other meanings. Maybe then alluding to "Nip=Jap" in cryptic clues? Not today!

Comment: Don't confuse a wind-up toy with the British expression: to wind someone up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If something is 'windup', or more usually, 'wind-up', it is powered by a spring which needs to be tightened (wound up) using a key or knob. This type of mechanism is often called 'clockwork'. Wind-up items include watches, clocks, and toys such as cars, boats, trains, and,yes, clockwork angels.

> wind-up
> adjective [ before noun ]
> A wind-up toy, watch, etc. has a
> key or part that you turn in order to make it operate:
> *a wind-up
> alarm clock*

[Wind-up (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wind-up)

[image]

Comment: I once saw a cartoon where a little tin-man type of toy with a wind-up mechanism sticking out of its back was bent over nearly double, laughing derisively at a puppet for its strings.

Comment: The hyphen, in my opinion, is de rigueur.